# Do R formulas treat functions and lags of variables like variables, across packages?

Tags: r, function, time-series, formula, lag

I am planning to use a bunch of different R packages that perform regression-like analysis to estimate versions of an equation with varying lag structures on the dependent and independent variables and on the error terms. All of these packages take a formula as the primary input, as in

```
my_regression_01   <- Y ~ X + Z + T
```

My question is this: Will pretty much any R package perforing a regression-like operation on an R formula also accept arbitrary functions of single variables, or of `I()` of functions of multiple variables, on the left- and right-hand side? Or do I have to somehow test each individual package to make sure it is treating such variables in the way I want? for instance, can I just assume that a formula like:

```
my_regression_02   <- log(Y) ~ log(X) + log(I((Z^2 + T^2)^0.5))
```

will always, or almost always, be treated as equivilent to:

```
ln_Y  <- log(Y)
ln_X  <- log(X)
ln_D  <- log((Z^2 + T^2)^0.5)

my_regression_03   <- l_Y ~ l_X + l_D
```

Or if you can not use `I()` inside a function, that:

```
my_regression_04   <- log(Y) ~ log(X) + I((Z^2 + T^2)^0.5)
```

is eqivilent to:

```
D2  <- (Z^2 + T^2)^0.5
my_regression_05   <- l_Y ~ l_X + D2
```

and similarly, that other elements of the standard formula notation will also treat functions of variables as variables, as:

```
my_regression_06   <- log(Y) ~ log(X) * I((Z^2 + T^2)^0.5)
```

is equivilent to:

```
my_regression_07   <- log(Y) ~ log(X) + I((Z^2 + T^2)^0.5) + I(log(X) * I((Z^2 + T^2)^0.5))
```

here assuming (correctly?) that `I()` can be used inside of `I()`, whether or not it can be used inside other functions, or to:

```
l_X_times_D <- log(X) * (Z^2 + T^2)^0.5)
my_regression_08   <- log(Y) ~ log(X) + l_X_times_D
```

if it can not.

And finally, can I assume accross packages that lags of functions of variables, and functions of lags of variables, will be treated as if they had been assigned to a variable and that variable was then included in the formula?

```
my_regression_09 <- log(Y) ~ log(lag(X)) + lag(log(Z))
```

is eqivilent to:

```
l_lag1_X  <- log(lag(X))
lag1_l_Z  <- lag(log(Z))
my_regression_10 <- log(Y) ~ l_lag1_X + lag1_l_Z
```

Comment: Formulas are really just collections of unevaluated symbols. Package functions may choose to interpret those symbols in different ways in different contexts. Most modeling functions pass the formula off to a function like `model.matrix()` or `model.frame()`. The behavior should be consistent for those functions that do. But you'd need to test what other functions do that do not use the standard helper functions.

Comment: There is no rules on CRAN on what a package should do. You can release your own package and chose to choose that for the methods of your package log in a formula means sinus and + means exp (that'd be silly though). As told MrFlick, formulas are unevaluated expressions.

A good practice is always to check the doc of a package when you use it.

Comment: So it sounds like I should be pretty safe, but not absolutely safe, if I open up the hood of paste0(model_type_abbeviation, "m") (as in model_type_abbeviation = l for linear: lm) and find something sort of like  x <- model.matrix(model.matrix.arguments); do.call(paste0(model_type_abbeviation, "m.fit"), 
args = list(x, other_arguments_to_fitting_function)).  And check the documentation if that doessn't work. If that's right I'll take your comment as an answer, @MrFlick